# Add the date to animation in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, animation

I have the gift of drought index (SPI), and I want to add the date, but it is not working:

Here is the link to the code:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/550145e2a10d622a2b83cae539c8a978

```
var tempCol = ee.ImageCollection('GRIDMET/DROUGHT')
 .filterDate('2010-01-01', '2022-12-31')
.select('spi1y');

 // Define a function to calculate the mean for each year
 var calculateAnnualMean = function(year) {
var start = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 1, 1);
var end = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 12, 31);
var annualMean = tempCol
.filterDate(start, end)
.mean()
.set('year', year);
return annualMean;
};
// Get a list of years in your date range
var years = ee.List.sequence(2010, 2022);

// Map over the years and calculate the annual mean for each year
var annualMeans = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(years.map(calculateAnnualMean));

 // Convert each image to an RGB visualization image by mapping the visualize
 // function over the image collection using the arguments defined previously.
var annualMeansVis = annualMeans.map(function(img) {
return img.visualize(colorbarOptions2);
  });

 // Import country features and filter to South American countries.
var states = ee.FeatureCollection("TIGER/2018/States");

// Define animation region (South America with buffer).
  var southAmAoi = ee.Geometry.Rectangle({
 coords: [-125, 24, -66, 49],
   geodesic: false
  });

 // Define an empty image to paint features to.
 var empty = ee.Image().byte();

 // Paint country feature edges to the empty image.
var southAmOutline = empty
 .paint({featureCollection: states, color: 1, width: 1})
 // Convert to an RGB visualization image; set line color to black.
 .visualize({palette: '000000'});

// Map a blend operation over the collection to overlay the country
// border outline image on all collection images.
var annualMeansOutline = annualMeansVis.map(function(img) {
return img.blend(southAmOutline);
});

   // Define animation arguments.
  var videoArgs = {
  dimensions: 768,
  region: southAmAoi,
  framesPerSecond: 1,
  crs: 'EPSG:3857'
  };
   // Import gena's package which allows text overlay on image
   var text = require('users/gena/packages:text'); 

   // define annotation params
    var annotations = [
    {position: 'right', offset: '2%', margin: '2%', property: 
   'label', scale: Map.getScale()}];

 // function to add text to animation
 function addText(image){
// get the time stamp (Date) of each frame
 var timeStamp = ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start')); 
 var timeStamp = timeStamp.format('YYYY'); //convert time stamp to string 
  var image = image.visualize(colorbarOptions2)
 .set({label:timeStamp}); // set a property called label for each image
// create a new image with the label overlayed using gena's package
 var annotated = text.annotateImage(image, {}, point, annotations); 

 return annotated 
  }
//add time stamp to all images
var tempColl = annualMeansOutline.map(addText) 

// Print the GIF URL to the console.
// print(tempColl.getVideoThumbURL(videoArgs)); 

// animate the gif
print(ui.Thumbnail(tempColl, videoArgs));
```